# How to delete sql entries on click

Tags: android

Lets say i had a a button that cycles through numbers how can i store the number but if the next array is displayed then delete the previous entry so on so on and so on. When i keep on pressing the button it diplays 1, 2 , 3 but i want it to show a single value.

Code example:

```
        final CharSequence[] items = {"1", "2", "3"};            
        if (value < items.length) {
           String s = (String)items[value];
           sqlName.setText(s);

            String sRow1 = sqlName.getText().toString();
            long lRow1 = Long.parseLong(sRow1);
            HotOrNot ex1 = new HotOrNot(this);
            ex1.open();
            ex1.deleteEntry(lRow1);
            ex1.close();
        }


            String name = sqlName.getText().toString();
            HotOrNot entry = new HotOrNot(SQLiteExample.this);
            entry.open();
            entry.createEntry(name);
            entry.close();

            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't follow; can you restate the question? What I am gathering is that you wish to display "1", then when the button is pressed, display "2" and so on.

- Is your code displaying "1, 2, 3" or "1", then "2", then "3" now? If it is the former, there may be a problem with how you are displaying the numbers.
- Also, if the HotOrNot class is relevant can you explain it's function?
- Is the concern with the display or editing the CharSequence in code?

Further:

```
sqlName.setText(s); 

String sRow1 = sqlName.getText().toString();
```

looks like it can be shortened to `String sRow1 = s` as you are getting the very string you just used.